Dimension of Kernel of a linear functional is co-dimension 1
Let $ B = \{ v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n \} $ be a basis of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$,
and let $\{ f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n \} $ be the corresponding dual basis i.e basis of $ V^*$, such that,
$$f_i(v_j) = \delta_{ij}.$$
Now, consider the linear functional $g = f_1 + f_2 $, and I want to find the dimension of $ \ker(g) $.
First, we know that the kernel of a functional $ f \in V^*$ is defined as:
$\ker(f) = \{ v \in V \mid f(v) = 0 \}.
$
By the Rank-Nullity Theorem, since the range of $ g $ is 1-dimensional (as dimension of underlying field is 1) , we have:
$\text{rank}(g) = 1.$
Applying the Rank-Nullity Theorem:
$
\dim(V) = \text{rank}(g) + \dim(\ker(g)),
$
which gives:
$
\dim(\ker(g)) = n - 1.
$
Now, we compute $ g(v_1)$ and $g(v_2) :$
$
g(v_1) = (f_1 + f_2)(v_1) = f_1(v_1) + f_2(v_1) = 1 + 0 = 1,
$
$
g(v_2) = (f_1 + f_2)(v_2) = f_1(v_2) + f_2(v_2) = 0 + 1 = 1.
$
For the remaining basis vectors $ v_3, v_4, \dots, v_n $, we get:
$
g(v_i) = 0 \quad \text{for all} \quad i \geq 3.
$
Thus, $ g $ is non-zero on $ v_1$ and  $v_2 $, and zero on the remaining basis vectors.
Given this, I was expecting the dimension of $ \ker(g) $ to be $ n - 2$ , since two linearly independent basis vectors,
$ v_1$ and $v_2$, do not vanish under $ g $. However, according to the Rank-Nullity Theorem, the dimension of $ \ker(g)$ is $ n - 1 $.
Where is the mistake in my reasoning? Is there something I am overlooking in how the kernel of $ g $ is determined?

The vectors $v_3,\dots,v_n$ are part of the kernel, but they do not span it. Note that $(f_1 + f_2)(v_1-v_2) = f_1(v_1 - v_2) + f_2(v_1 - v_2) = 1 - 0 + 0 - 1 = 0$. This means that $v_1 - v_2$ is also an element of the kernel. Now $v_1-v_2,v_3,\dots,v_n$ do form a basis of the kernel.

You missed $v_1-v_2$. Since $g(v_1)=g(v_2)=1$, we have $v_1-v_2\in\ker g$. This vector along with the rest of the $v_i$s forms a basis of $\ker g$ (though this needs proof.)
Other than this, there are some problems with your arguments.

since the range of $ g $ is 1-dimensional (as dimension of underlying field is 1)

This is not immediately obvious. It is entirely possible that $g\equiv0$, in which case, range of $g$ will be $0$-dimensional. You need to come up with an argument that shows $g\not\equiv0$ (for example, $g(v_1)=1\neq0$).

Thus, $ g $ is non-zero on $ v_1$ and  $v_2 $, and zero on the remaining basis vectors. Given this, I was expecting the dimension of $ \ker(g) $ to be $ n - 2$ , since two linearly independent basis vectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$, do not vanish under $ g $. However, according to the Rank-Nullity Theorem, the dimension of $ \ker(g)$ is $ n - 1 $.

The basis vectors vanishing or not has nothing to do with the kernel. Consider the map $f_1+f_2+\cdots+f_n$. This does not vanish on any basis vector, yet has kernel of dimension $n-1$. You should perhaps give a reread of the definitions and do more examples to avoid these kind of misunderstandings.
Hope this helps. :)

Yeah I got it. I just considered g to be non zero linear functional as I have defined it. And yes I I have a lot of misunderstandings with the concept. Thanks
